# init.d script not working?

Tags: debian, init.d, vnc

I copied an init script from [here](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc) quite some time ago to automatically start my tightvncserver at boot. It worked perfectly at the time. Since then, I have reformatted my computer, and now my script doesn't start automatically. If I call /etc/init.d/tightvncserver start manually via ssh, then my vnc server starts as it should... Any idea as to what's going on?

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/tightvncserver
# http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc
#Set the VNCUSER variable to the name of the user to start tightvncserver
VNCUSER='jake'
case "$1" in
  start)
    su $VNCUSER -c '/usr/bin/tightvncserver :2'
    echo "Starting TightVNC server for $VNCUSER "
    ;;
  stop)
    pkill Xtightvnc
    echo "Tightvncserver stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/tightvncserver {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: What's `jake`'s user look like?  Any interesting errors on the console?  Maybe echo the return code after the command is attempted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your init script has no symlinks in the rc*.d directories run the following to create them:

```
update-rc.d tightvncserver defaults
```

Comment: Yep, that was the trick. I remember running that command previously, but it slipped my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if your script is enabled in runlevels :

Method 1 :

`ls /etc/rc?.d/`

Method 2 :

```
apt-get install chkconfig
chkconfig --list
```

Comment: I think `update-rc.d` is the preferred method in Debian.

Comment: I Shane, and I can think of at least 2 others methods too. Would you please edit the post and provide hints about using update-rc.d ?